# Given $a \in \mathbb Q$ which is non-zero, show that $1/a \in \mathbb Q$.

Tags: proof-verification

Any idea?

I've started with $a= p/q$, meaning $q$ has to be rational.

Then $1/a= q/p$ But surely this could be irrational if, say $p=9$, $q=4$?

Comment: I think $4/9$ is a rational number.

Comment: A rational number is the ratio of integers. Suppose $a = p/q$ is rational and nonzero. Then $p,q$ are integers, with $p,q\neq 0$. Then $1/a = q/p$. Since $p,q$ are still integers, notice that $1/a$ is rational. I think what you're thinking of are *improper fractions* as opposed to irrational numbers. (Well ... maybe. I'm not sure.)

Comment: A number is rational if it has the form $\frac{n}{m}$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\not = 0$. So both $\frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{q}{p}$ are rationals.

Comment: Yeah my bad I'm being thick today lol

Comment: Q is generally defined as being the field extension of the integers. According to that definition, the fact that the multiplicative inverse is in Q simply follows from the definition of field. So the first questions to ask with this sort of problem are "What definition of a rational number are we working with?" and "What is the definition of 1/a?"

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a real number $x$ is irrational if and only if there are integers $m$ and $n\not=0$ such that $x=m/n$. If $x\not=0$, then $m\not= 0$, so, as you pointed out $1/x=n/m$. This number is by definition rational!

Comment: omg thats bad lol. Having a dead-brain day lol. Thanks